# jsf 2 spring application logging specific events

Tags: spring, jsf-2, architecture

I have an JSF2 app which uses Spring for transactions,security and DI container.
The application has 3 layers :
1. JSF view + JSF Managed Bean
2. Service classes
3. DAO classes
So, a request is something like:
JSF Page -> JSF MB -> Service class -> DAO Class -> DB, and the the other way around.
My problem is that there are service methods that after perform their business had to log to DB that event.
For instance, when someone activates/deactivates a user. I want to log this action along with the user id.
So, I only see two approaches here : (I`m sure there are more)
1. inside this method I determine the logged in user and perform the actual logging
  - as i disadvantages here I would see the fact that this method will be not so easy to test, because of the userId picked from SpringSecurity
2. Using SpringAOP. This way would be noninvasive, which is cool, but then I would have an aspect for one method, which is not so efficient.

I would like to know if you guys had this kind of issues and if so, how did you solve them ?

Comment: I have a similar situation in my built system. We just keep the logged in user in a session scoped bean. When user performs any operation which changes DB state, an update operation over the logger table is done. Actually we call it manually after every time we perform each operation. Could be done in a more elegant way using Spring AOP? Probably, letting the container manage each method call  we're interested in and making it call to the logger method each time DB is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider introducing a marker annotation. Let's call it: @LogEvent. Then annotate every method you wish to intercept. This way you can implement a single aspect with an advice that matches not on naming convention but on the presence of @LogEvent.

something like:

```
@After("execution(@LogEvent * *.*(..))")
```